# Bind a property to the body of a request without the FromBody attribute in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

#### The Problem

I need to find a way to bind a property on a class to the body of an http request in ASP.NET Core MVC, and I need to do it without using the `FromBody` attribute.

I have the following class:

```cs
public class SaveEntity 
{
    // This property should be bound from the URL.
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // This property should be bound from the body.
    public SaveEntityParameters Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I intend to use it in a controller.

```cs
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class EntitiesController : Controller 
{
    readonly IBus _bus;
    public EntitiesController(IBus bus) 
    {
        if (bus == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bus));
        _bus = bus;
    }
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(SaveEntity command) 
    {
        var response = await _bus.SendAsync(command);
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

The `SaveEntity` class is located in a class library that does not have a dependency on MVC, so that's why the `FromBody` attribute is unavailable. How can I bind the `Payload` property of the `SaveEntity` class to the body while keeping the `Id` property bound to the url?

#### A Less Ideal Work-Around

I've thought about splitting up the `Id` and `Payload` properties. Then I could do this:

```cs
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Guid id, [FromBody]SaveEntityParameters payload)
{
    SaveEntity command = new SaveEntity {Id = id, Payload = payload};
    var response = await _bus.SendAsync(command);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

But then I have to manually assign the properties of the `SaveEntity` instance before I can use it. I'd like to avoid the manual assignment, if possible, because this type of thing will be happening in several controllers.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but you could also do something like below:

```
public class SaveEntityDTO
{
    [FromRoute]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public SaveEntityParameters Payload { get; set; }

    public SaveEntity GetEntity() 
    {
      return new SaveEntity { Id = Id, Payload = Payload };
    }
}
```

Action: `public async Task<IActionResult> Put(SaveEntityDTO saveEntityDTO)`

I think ideally you need a custom model binder which knows to bind `SaveEntity`

Comment: Thanks for providing this. Yeah, this solution seems similar to the work-around in my question. But this would come in handy if I ended up using the same SaveEntity class in several different controller methods. I think you're on the right track with the custom model binder. I looked into this as well but couldn't find an elegant way of binding nested types with it.